# Tweepy filtering multiple location

Tags: python, tweepy

So I am using the Tweepy to try and get streams from several squared locations to work on a GIS project. I tried using a list as a filter but it seems to not be possible:

```
l = StdOutListener()
stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(locations={[-4.62,41.97,10.49,51.1],[-87.6,24.73,-75.41,32.12]}) #Doesn't work
```

Does anyone knows if there is any alternative, since multiple threads would also not work since they check IPs so multiple Auths would not work either.

Comment: So you can't connect from multiple instances from the same outbound IP?  If so, there is no way to resolve this programmatically without having access to either another IP, or spinning up something in the cloud.

Comment: looking at the source code you can only pass in a list of 4 coordinates

Comment: Ah damn what a pain in the ass. And yes @ eatmeimadanish i read somewhere around here, when someone else was asking about multiple auth on tweet4j, someone else said twitter checks IPs so if you want multiple streams, ya gotta have multiple IPs.

Anyways, thanks guys.

Comment: yea if you look here it has to be a multiple of 4 meaning one list --> https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py#L437

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the locations section of the [parameter listing in the Developer documentation for the Streaming end-point](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters.html):

> -122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8,-74,40,-73,41

translates to

> San Francisco OR New York City

so, accordingly, your code should be formatted to

`...
stream.filter(locations=[-4.62,41.97,10.49,51.1,-87.6,24.73,-75.41,32.12])`

as a single list of all locations following the South-West and North-East grouping; thereby, as a sanity check please ensure that your locations list be a multiple of four (allowing for a latitude and longitude each for SW and NE coordinates for each bounding box) and also that NE coordinates > SW coordinates.

Please be sure to keep in mind that the [stream API end-point permits](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter) the filtering of only

> ...25 0.1-360 degree location boxes.

Comment: May I know how the location list you use as filter parameter was generated?

Comment: it will follow the pattern of 
`[city_one_SW_longitude, city_one_SW_latitude, city_one_NE_longitude, city_one_NE_latitude, city_two_SW_longitude, city_two_SW_latitude, city_two_NE_longitude, city_two_NE_latitude, city_three_SW_longitude, ...]`